# Lognormal-mixture dynamics and calibration to market volatility smiles

Tags: programming, implied-volatility, lognormal

Can someone assist me in replicating the code and results from page 11, Figure 3 of the paper 'Lognormal-mixture dynamics and calibration to market volatility smiles' by Damiano Brigo, Fabio Mercurio, and Francesco Rapisarda, available at [https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/~dbrigo/lognsmile.pdf](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Edbrigo/lognsmile.pdf)? I have posted my code attempt, but it does not perfectly match the one in the paper. Any help or guidance on achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class LognormalMixture(object):
    """
    *
    * Title: Lognormal-mixture dynamics and calibration 
    * to market volatility smiles.
    * From: Damiano Brigo, Fabio Mercurio, Francesco Rapisarda.
    *
    """
    class Shifted(object):
        """
        *
        * From chapter 4: Shifting the overall distribution.
        * Quote: "We now show how to construct an even more general model 
        * by shifting the process (11), while preserving the correct drift. 
        * Precisely, we assume that the new asset-price process A0 is obtained
        * through the following affine transformation of the process S ...".
        *
        """
        def _sigma_0 \
        (
            lambda_: np.ndarray, eta_: np.ndarray, t: float, alpha: float
        ) -> float:
            """
            *
            * \sigma(0) is the ATM-forward implied volatility.
            *
            * @param array $lambda_ - weights of each lognormal dist.
            * @param array $eta_    - volatilities standardized by time
            * @param float $t       - maturity
            * @param float $alpha   - 
            *
            """
            return 2/np.sqrt(t) * norm.ppf((1 - alpha) * np.sum(lambda_ * \
                norm.cdf(0.5 * eta_ * np.sqrt(t))) + 0.5 * alpha)

        def _sigma_m \
        (
            k: np.ndarray, s0: float, mu: float, lambda_: np.ndarray, 
            eta_: np.ndarray, t: float, alpha: float
        ) -> float:
            """
            *
            * Shifting the overall distribution:
            * Black-Scholes volatility derived from array of log-moneyness.
            *
            * @param array $m       - log moneyness
            * @param array $lambda_ - weights of each lognormal dist.
            * @param array $eta_    - volatilities standardized by time
            * @param float $t       - maturity
            * @param float $alpha   -
            *
            """
            # calculte log-moneyness 
            k_a = k - s0 * alpha * np.exp(mu*t)
            a0 = s0 * (1 - alpha)
            m = np.log(a0/k_a) + mu * t

            # atm-forward implied volatilities
            sigma_0: float = LognormalMixture.Shifted._sigma_0(
                lambda_, eta_, t, alpha)

            # black-scholes implied-volatilities
            sigma_m = sigma_0
            sigma_m += alpha * m * (np.sum(lambda_ * \
                norm.cdf(-0.5 * eta_ * np.sqrt(t))) - 0.5) * (np.sqrt(t) / \
                np.sqrt(np.pi*2) * np.exp(-0.125 * sigma_0**2 * t))**-1
            return sigma_m + 0.5 * ((t*(1-alpha))**-1 * np.sum(lambda_/eta_ * \
                np.exp(0.125*t*(sigma_0**2-eta_**2))) - (sigma_0*t)**-1 + \
                0.25 * alpha**2 * sigma_0 * t * ((np.sum(lambda_ * norm.cdf(
                -0.5 * eta_ * np.sqrt(t))) - 0.5)/ (np.sqrt(t)/np.sqrt(
                np.pi*2) * np.exp(-0.125 * sigma_0**2 * t)))**2) * m**2  
        

lnm = LognormalMixture.Shifted
k_ = np.arange(80,121,0.5)
lambda_ = np.array([0.6,0.4])
s0 = 100
t = 2
plt.figure(figsize=(11,7))

# sp1
plt.subplot(121)
plt.grid()
plt.plot(k_, lnm._sigma_m(k=k_, s0=s0, mu=0.05, lambda_=lambda_, 
    eta_=np.array([0.35,0.1]),  t=t, alpha=0.0), label="α=0.0", c="b")
plt.plot(k_, lnm._sigma_m(k=k_, s0=s0, mu=0.05, lambda_=lambda_, 
    eta_=np.array([0.35,0.1]),  t=t, alpha=-0.2), label="α=-0.2", c="g", ls="--")
plt.plot(k_, lnm._sigma_m(k=k_, s0=s0, mu=0.05, lambda_=lambda_, 
    eta_=np.array([0.35,0.1]),  t=t, alpha=-0.4), label="α=-0.4", c="r", ls=":")
plt.legend()

# sp2
plt.subplot(122)
plt.grid()
plt.plot(k_, lnm._sigma_m(k=k_, s0=s0, mu=0.05, lambda_=lambda_, 
    eta_=np.array([0.35,0.1]),  t=t, alpha=0.0), label="α=0.0", c="b")
plt.plot(k_, lnm._sigma_m(k=k_, s0=s0, mu=0.05, lambda_=lambda_, 
    eta_=np.array([0.1099,0.3553]),  t=t, alpha=-0.2), label="α=-0.2", c="g", ls="--")
plt.plot(k_, lnm._sigma_m(k=k_, s0=s0, mu=0.05, lambda_=lambda_, 
    eta_=np.array([0.09809,0.2979]),  t=t, alpha=-0.4), label="α=-0.4", c="r", ls=":")
plt.legend()
```